# Django Migrate Exclusion of Specific Models to Different Databases

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I have been struggling with this aggravation for a little bit, and I have not been able to find a definitive answer elsewhere online.

I have a Django app that uses multiple databases; a **default** db and then a **client** db. The **default** db holds **universal tables**. The **client** db holds **custom data/tables created by the client who uses my application**.

I understand how `migrations` work, but I am using 2 databases that should not have the same models included when I run migrations. **client**'s should have the client tables and the **default** db should hold the universal data.

It is also important to note (because of the question below) that I do not make application specific models (other than the default ones auto-generated by **Django** itself), I use 2 packages/applications for this: `objects` and `objects_client`, `objects` holds the **default** db models and `objects_client` holds the **client** db models.

`client_db` is also the name I use in **settings.py**

Now here is my issue:

I know I can run `python3 manage.py migrate objects_client --database=client_db` and `python3 manage.py migrate objects --database=default`, but I don't want to have to individually specify the **admin**, **auth**, **contenttypes**, and **sessions** migrations to the default database so I also run, `python3 manage.py migrate`, which obviously places `objects_client` in the default DB as well (which I don't want).

How do I go about runing the a version of the default `python3 manage.py migrate` command with an exclusion of an app, i.e. `objects_client`, without changing each model in that app to **managed=false** (because that is a pain)?

Here is the output of `showmigrations` if it helps decribe what I mean in more detail, these are the apps being migrated.

```
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
objects
 [X] 0001_initial
objects_client
 [X] 0001_initial
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
```

Answer (score 1):

Set up a database routing scheme with [Database routers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers) and provide an [`allow_migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/#allow_migrate) method to determine if the migration operation is allowed to run on the database with alias `db`.

```
class Router:
    ...
    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the objects_client app only appears in the 'client_db'
        database.
        """
        if app_label == 'objects_client':
            return db == 'client_db'
        return None
```

Finally, in the `settings.py` file, add the following

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.Router']
```

Comment: I won't be able to check this for a few days, but can you provide an example that provides a router that disallows `objects_client` to be migrated to the default DB when `python3 manage.py migrate` is run? My issue is that your solution is valid as is for specifying which DB `objects_client` hits when I specifically run migrations for it, but the real problem is that I want to be able to run all migrations but `objects_client` to the default DB using the above migrate command. Or are you saying this accomplishes what I am asking too?